# Pushing message to groups in SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Just trying to wrap my mind around handling pushing data to ***some users*** through `SignalR`.

Say, in a private chat situation, `Person A` sends a message to `Person B`. If I'm understanding the concept correctly, I need to create a `Group` for each user who logged into the system. This way, when the new message from `Person A` comes in, in my `SignalR Hub`, I'd send the message to the group for `Person B` which only has only one user in it i.e. `Person B`.

In this approach, I'd essentially create a unique `Group` for each user so that I have the flexibility to push data to each unique user. I could use the `UserId` as the `Group` Id.

Is this the way to handle pushing data selectively to each unique user?

Comment: Yes, in the case of the sending a to b you can just filter by client id

Comment: Thank you. So, if my application is a popular one, then I'll end up with a lot of groups which brings a question about `SignalR`'s scalability. Do you think that would be an issue?

Comment: I offload sending push my hub to a background service so the initial update can happen and return, and then the background worker handles sending my hubs so it not too much of an issue

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm also looking into Azure SignalR service for scalability.

Comment: thats even better you they have a more reliable way for of loading the background task.

Comment: I've posted a simple example on how to send by client Id

Comment: please let me know if there is anything else I can do to resolve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab client Ids manully like so and then send them using the hubcontext to avoid creating a lot of groups (you just need to implement a menthod which get you're connections from your resource in my case im using dtos)

I'm assuming your hubs have some type of connection manager, here's a sample of one from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#in-memory-storage)

In my case I have a dynamic configuration which I use to configure my hubs using the Type of DTO, and I send hubs using a generic hub base here is a sample implementation:

Warning: things may slightly be different I'm using .Net-Core in this example

```cs
//NOTE: THub must be the one Registered with MapHubs in the Startup 
//class or your connections won't be there because Hubs are not contravarient
public abstract class HubBase<TDTO, THub> : Hub
    Where THub: HubBase<TDTO, THub>
{
    protected IHubContext<THub> hubContext;
    HubBase(IHubContext<THub> hubContext)
    {
       this._hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    protected abstract List<string> GetConnectionsByDto(TDTO dto)

    protected async Task SendFilteredAsync(string eventName, TDTO dto)
    {
        var clientIds = await this.GetConnectionsByDto(dto);

        if (false == clientIds.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var broadcastTasks = clientIds.Select(async clientId =>
                                    await this._hubContext.Clients.Client(clientId).SendAsync(eventName, dto));

        await Task.WhenAll(broadcastTasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could use a bit more clarification. I think in your example, ClientId is the UserId. And I think you're suggesting I keep a record of connection Id's for each person so that when the message arrives, I can look up connection Id's that I need to push the message to using client Id's. Is that the idea?

Comment: @Sam I’m under the assumption that the hubs are using some implementation of a connection manager which tracks your users based off of some key eg userId or jwt subject.  If you’re sending a dto there should be a way for you to filter the userIds you need to send that to eg just get the sender and receiver and look up there connections

Comment: Yes, when the message arrives at my hub, my DTO has Id's of users that are part of that private chat. That part is easy. But currently, I don't store the connection Id assigned to the user anywhere. If I'm understanding your example correctly, you're suggesting I should store it somewhere so that I can simply say, give me connection ID's for users A and B, then push the message to those connections. If this is what you're suggesting, I'll have to store UserId, ConnectionId key value pairs somewhere.

Comment: @Sam when a user connect, you map the logged in user to their connection(s) (if you allow a user to use multiple devices), then when you send you check to filter the connection manager based on the key, current I use my JWT subjectId but you could just use a simple userId

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I'm not currently mapping UserId's with their ConnectionId's. Looks like that's the first thing I need to do.

Comment: @Sam, yeah start by mapping your connection.  I don't like groups because in order to create a group you need to know all of the potential groups ahead of time e.g who already has conversations mapped.  That's why I just use a connection manager, because at anytime I can know whose mapped to a userId, and generally the DTO's you're sending will have a userId associated

Comment: Thank you for the link to the docs. I think in my case I'll also have to use Redis for storing that data because my app runs on Azure App Service and as it scales, it may have multiple instances so the in memory storage won't work.

Comment: @Sam, I see, you can use a connection manager from the DB, the but its just more trouble some.  The same concepts should apply

Comment: I already use Redis in my app so I think that's the way to go. It's not cheap but fast and reliable. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Looks like if we use `ClaimsPrincipal` to identify the user, `SignalR` automatically knows what connections the user has open and sends the message. I tested it and it works fine. Are you not using `ClaimsPrincipal`? Looks like with this approach, there's no need to worry about `userId` to `connectionId` mapping. `SignalR` seems to take care of it automatically.

Comment: @Sam I use the subjectId in my claims principal as the key for the connection manager, is that what you’re referring to or is there some other built in way you’re referring to?

Comment: In my case, with the message I send to my `Hub`, I send the `Id`'s of all the users who are in the chat. In my `Chat` object, I have all the participants of that particular chat readily available to me. So when I send the message to the `Hub` which contains the `UserId`'s, I just issue `await Clients.User(userId.ToString()).SendAsync("new_message", message);` and that particular user gets the message. `SignalR` seems to have a built-in way of mapping `UserId`s with `ConnectionId'`s

Comment: Interesting, that’s good to know, Using a token server currently I don’t plug into user management, but it’s on my list of things todo, Thanks